# Bash Scripting - Condition with brace expansion

Tags: bash, shell

I've recently had a problem with my bash exercise which is to create a script to check if a date entered by a user matches certain dates of mine.

To break it down a bit more, my exercise is meant to check pattern matches with brace expansion, but it has been very tricky since I tried these lines below and none of them worked. I hope you guys can help me out.

```
echo -e "Enter your birthday: \c"
read birthday

WoodRat={19240205..19250123}


if [[ $birthday =~ $WoodRat ]]; then

echo "Your Chinese Zodiac is: Wood Rat "

else

echo "Sorry, cant find any matches."

fi
```

Comment: Note that even if `$WoodRat` contained a list of numbers (it doesn't), it would also contain a lot of invalid date values (19249999, for example).  Using `bash -x yourscript` would have shown you what is in `$WoodRat`, and you'd be able to answer your own question.  It's a fundamental technique for debugging a script.  Alternatively, write your own `echo` statements; adding `echo $WoodRat` after the assignment would show you the problem too.

Answer (score 2):

Brace expansion is not the right tool here: the literal string, not a list of values, is assigned to `WoodRat`, and `{19240205..192501123}` is not a regular expression to test if a value is in a range. You are better off with explicit minimum and maximum values:

```
WoodRat=(19240205 19250123)

if (( birthday >= ${WoodRat[0]} && birthday <= ${WoodRat[1]} )); then
  echo "Your Chinese Zodiac is: Wood Rat "
else
  echo "Sorry, cant find any matches."
fi
```

Comment: The `[1]` means the second one (which is the last one in this example).  The `WoodRat=(A B)` assignment makes an array (the parentheses do that) with two values in the array.

Comment: Strictly speaking, you wouldn't have to use an array; you could have to separate values `WoodRatFirst` and `WoodRatLast`. The array just preserves the idea of one parameter hold the "range" of values that defines a wood rat.

Answer (score 1):

Brace expansion and regular expressions are different things. Brace expansion expands to multiple elements, while regex matches a pattern.

You should use numerical comparisons instead:

```
if [[ $birthday -ge 19240205 && $birthday -le 19250123 ]]
```

To do it with brace expansion, you'd need to compare against each element:

```
# Very inefficient, never use this:
for num in {19240205..19250123}
do
  if [[ $birthday = $num ]] 
  then ...
```